# How to write a type declaration for UMD global js library

Tags: javascript, typescript, global-variables, typescript-typings, umd

I'm trying to enhance a third-party js library with typing.

Consider the following structure of the js library:

```
'use strict';
var AutoModel = AutoModel || {};
if (typeof AutoModel.constructed === "undefined") {    
  (function (o) {
    function open() {
      ...
    }

    o.Motor = new function() {
      function start()...
    }

    ...
    o.constructed = true;
  })(AutoModel);
}
```

The js is loaded in the `<script>` section and in my ts file it would use it like:

```
declare const AutoModel: any;

export class TestClass {
  doSomething(): void {
    AutoModel.open();
    AutoModel.Motor.start();
  }
}
```

How can I write a d.ts that gives me typing and code completion for 'AutoModel'?
Would be cool if I could omit the redeclaration completely.

I've already tried a lot of different approaches but none leads to a completely satisfying solution.

Comment: What do you mean by ```omit the redeclaration completely```?

Comment: For example if I could declare it in the d.ts completely.
export var AutoModel: AutoModel;
export interface AutoModel {
  ...
}

This looks good until the moment I'm trying to add namespace 'AutoModel'.'Motor'